# Methods to login to website via python for scraping

Tags: c#, python, mobile, authentication, screen-scraping

so have tired a lot of methods to login to my college website

Ever method i have tired gives me 401, i have used mechanize request ntlm, all these give me a 401 so if there anyway.

Also keep in mind im trying to developing a mobile app, and going to be grabbing data from this website for ever user with there login info which i now how to do but can't seem to get past.

If not what other languages and can do this like C# or Vb.net but will they work on say like android and ios?

Update 18 December 10:27:
Got a 200 status code, because i was putting the wronge domain name, domain name has to be the server name which is used on the local network,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) with [requests_ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm):

```
    import requests
    from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

    requests.get("http://ntlm_protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))
```

Comment: I don't think his site is using HTTP Digest authentication, rather NTLM, but it seems there is a package which adds NTLM authentication to the Requests library: [requests-ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm)

Comment: when you say domain\\username, does it have to be example.com\username or is just username on its own?

Comment: Okay guys i rembered from college network that there domain was BURYCOLLEGE pluged that in and status of 200!!!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's a bit hard to reverse engineer this without a login to your college website, but from looking at that link, here's what I see:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

I'm no expert in Python but I do recall that historically NTLM has been painful, but not impossible, for non-Microsoft clients.

Certainly you should have no problem accessing this content using a .NET client.

Have you tried for example [python-ntlm](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/)? I see it's based on code from the [NTLM Authorization Proxy Server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) which I recall using many years ago to handle NTLM authentication.

Comment: yes i tired this but still throws out a 401, and im on backtrack using python 2.6 as i check before it says it was fixed,